# Expands SD card

Tags: sd-card

I have an SD image made for an 8 GB card and 8 I want to expand it to the size of my new card, 16 GB. I installed raspbian on my 8 GB card with NOOBS. How can I resize my SD card .IMG?

Answer (score 1):

Boot Raspbian and at the terminal enter
`sudo raspi-config` and there is an option to Expand the Filesystem.

Comment: doesn't work. Says filesystem not supported